# Why is there usually no correction for multiple comparisons in Bayesian statistics?

Tags: bayesian, multiple-comparisons

How would you explain to an only moderately statistically literate scientific reviewer that adjustment for multiple comparisons is not necessary when sampling from a Bayesian posterior?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203378.